# Activity is calling onStop after onCreate

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities: an onboarding activity, a log in activity and a 3rd activity. When the user open my app for the first time, it will go to onboarding, after log in activity and it will ask to login with google using firebase. When the user do it, It will start the 3rd activity and finish the old one, like that:

```
val intent = Intent(baseContext, SkyActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

But everytime the user logs in and starts the `3rd activity`, `onPause()` is called. It crashes the app, because my `onPause()` stops my background song:

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    if (backgroundSongService.isPlaying()) {
        backgroundSongService.pauseMusic()
    }
}
```

And at this time, my `backgroundSongService` is still `null` (I call a function that initializes it in my onCreate). So I get the error:

```
lateinit property backgroundSongService has not been initialized
```

But this happens **ONLY** when the user logs in. If he closes the app after logging in and open again, he'll still be logged in.
So the activities flow will be: `OnboardingActivity` -> `3rdActivity`

The OnboardingActivity will call the 3rd activity like that:

```
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    val intent = Intent(baseContext, SkyActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

Exactly like my `Intent` inside the `LoginActivity`. But the difference is that, this time, the `onPause` won't be called in the 3rd activity. Why is it called only after the `LoginActivity`?

Comment: You're improperly using `lateinit`. Since it's possible for the song service to be null, it should be a nullable parameter. Then you can use a safe call on it. `backgroundSongService?.run{ if (isPlaying()) pauseMusic() }`

Answer (score 0):

**Quick work-around to your problem of crashing**

Verify that background service is not null before using it

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    if (backgroundSongService!=null && backgroundSongService.isPlaying()) {
        backgroundSongService.pauseMusic()
    }
}
```

Comment: But the `pauseMusic()` is inside the 3rd activity, not inside the previous activity. So how can it call `onPause()` of 2nd activity and run the code inside the `onPause()` of the 3rd activity?

Comment: Where do you log in ? In Third Activity?

Comment: The onPause is actually caused by its own activity and not other activity.

Comment: onPause will be called only when some other activity opens and pushes current activity to paused state or onBackpressed is called...

Comment: The log in is inside my second activity, the `pauseMusic()` is inside the `onPause()` of the 3rd activity

Comment: Apply the quick work around and see if there is any other activity launched by firebase, say for validating login after your 3rd activity is launched.